# How can I save only the image in an image view?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an iOS App. I'm pretty new to iOS dev. I'm using an image view in this app. The size of the image will vary - it is not static. It is centered in the view, and will always be the width of the screen. The height will vary. I am overlaying text overtop of the image.

My current code captures the entire screenshot, minus the navigation and toolbars. How can I modify my existing save image function to only capture the image being displayed rather than the full screen?

```
func generateImage() -> UIImage
{
    // hide toolbar and navbar
    toolBar.hidden = true
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

    // Render view to an image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.view.frame,
        afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let img : UIImage =
    UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // show toolbar and navbar
    toolBar.hidden = false
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

    return img
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are using a UIImageView in order to display the image. Then you have shown code that is taking a screenshot to get access to a UIImage object.

I may be very confused here, but the UIImageView class has a property called `image` that will give you the UIImage currently being displayed. Why not just grab this and use it wherever you need it?

```
let myImage = myImageView.image
```

Replace `myImageView` with a reference to your actual `UIImageView` instance inside your `UIViewController`.

[UIImageView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html)

Comment: Right, sorry - I should explain. I'm overlaying text overtop of the image. So I'm trying to save the image with the text overlay.